# There is any documentation for html tags interface in typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I want to know more about HTML tags interface on typescript and react ts 
like `HTMLButtonElement` or `React.MouseEvent` and so on 
I want to know how these work and what properties they have, but I couldn't find any fully supported documentation for it

Answer (score 0):

The ones not prefixed with `React` are just regular HTML elements/events. For example [HTMLButtonElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) has more info on MDN. The React-stuff can be found on react.dev, for example [React.MouseEvent](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#mouseevent-handler).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about HTML tag events (onChange, onClick, etc.), just do this.

```
<button onClick={(event) => doSomthing(event)}>Do Something</button>
```

Now, if you hover over the onClick event, a dialogue box will pop up, and you'll get to know the type of the event.